# R removing duplicate values based on two columns, with different "tolerance" values for each column

Tags: r, duplicates

I feel like I'm really close to getting this right, but can't seem to take that last step.

I have a data frame that looks like below:

```
df <- data.frame("Time" = c(1, 2, 2.01, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.05, 7),
                 "Speed" = c(10, 20, 23, 30, 40, 49, 50, 52, 60, 62, 70))
```

I'm trying to remove duplicates from both `Time` and `Speed`, but with different thresholds.

With `Time`, anything that has a difference of `<=0.05` is considered a duplicate - so (2, 2.01), (4, 4) and (6, 6.05) are duplicates.
With `Speed`, anything that has a difference of `<=5` is considered a duplicate - so (20, 23) and (60, 62) are duplicates.

Since (2, 2.01) and (6, 6.05) `Time` pairs also have duplicate `Speed` values, I would like to keep one row and remove the other duplicate. But since the (4, 4) `Time` pair has a different `Speed` value ((40, 49) is over my tolerance value 5), I'd like to completely get rid of that row.

So my final data frame would look like:

```
df2 <- data.frame("Time" = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 5.5, 6, 7),
                  "Speed" = c(10, 20, 30, 50, 52, 60, 70))
```

I found a way to remove duplicates for (2, 2.01) and (6, 6.05) pairs with the line of code below:

```
df[!duplicated(round(df$Time, 1)),]
```

But what's returned from the line above still includes `Time 4.0` and `Speed 40` in the 4th row, and I can't find a way to completely get rid of this row. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How big is the "real" data you're working with?  Is it possible that one observation may be duplicated with several others (rather than just one as in the example)?   Finally, just so I'm clear, if Time has a duplicate (e.g., 4, 4), but speed doesn't (e.g., 40, 49) you would remove _both_ rows, right?  I think the main problem is that you've got to evaluate all of the pairwise distances between observations on both variables.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong  The real data has thousands of rows, and will probably have more than two duplicates as you suggested. And yes, I'd like to remove both rows if Time has a duplicate but Speed doesn't

Comment: So if there are Times `2`, `2.02` and `2.06`. How does removing work?

Comment: @MartinGal That would again depend on what Speed looks like. If Speed values that correspond to Time is something like `10, 20, 30`, in that case I'd remove all three rows (since none of them has a difference smaller than 5). If values are `10, 12, 30`, I'd remove `30` and the corresponding Time, but keep either one of `10` or `12`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you remove `12` and `30`? `2.02` and `2.06` are less than `0.05` apart and `30 - 12 > 5`.

Comment: @MartinGal Because `10` and `12` are less than 5 apart, and `2` and `2.02` are less than `0.05` apart. I guess I should have made the example set too simplified, I can update it using the values from these comments.

Comment: I don't see a way around evaluating all of the pairs of differences on both variables and even doing that, with the multiple-duplicates potential it will still be complicated to figure out exactly what to do.

Comment: You could imagine doing this sequentially (i.e., in a loop), but you would risk removing observations, for example  T=(2, 2.02), S=(10,13) would both be removed, but if you encountered, for example (T=2.06, S=16) later on, that would remain in because you would have already removed the duplicate (T=2.02, S=13).  If the order of these observations in the data changed, the resulting dataset would change, unless you evaluated all potential duplicates of all potential duplicates at once.  Someone smarter than I am is going to have to figure this one out.